How to log coverage report to logs or summary?
I have a workflow that looks like this:
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  git_pull:
    runs-on: self-hosted
    steps:
    - name: executing remote ssh commands
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.4
      with:
        host: <IP addr>
        username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
        port: 22
        script_stop: true
        script: |
          cd /my-api
          rm -f /my-api/test-results.xml
          ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /root/.ssh/pubkey; git pull origin master'
          # Ensure the directory exists and has the correct permissions
          sudo mkdir -p /my-api
          sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /my-api
          systemctl stop my-api
          pytest --junit-xml=test-results.xml generated_tests.py
          coverage run -m pytest generated_tests.py
          coverage report > coverage-report.txt
          cat coverage-report.txt
          systemctl start my-api
    - name: Fetch and print coverage report
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.4
      with:
        host: <IP addr>
        username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
        port: 22
        script_stop: true
        script: |
          cat /my-api/coverage-report.txt >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

    - name: Surface failing tests
      if: always()
      uses: pmeier/pytest-results-action@main
      with:
        path: /my-api/test-results.xml
        summary: true
        fail-on-empty: true
        title: Test results


As you can see, I have been trying to log the coverage report but it is not logging.
This won't print the coverage report in any way in spite of me trying many variations of cat, tee and >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
What is an easy way to log the coverage report into the GitHub logs or the summary page?

Your report is being generated on your server. You can scp the report back to runner. See https://github.com/appleboy/scp-action but apparently it doesn't support the copy from host to runner. Here's the relevant open issue: https://github.com/appleboy/scp-action/issues/176.

You could try this step:
  - name: Fetch and print coverage report
    run:
      # Download report from the host via ssh
      echo ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }} > key
      ssh -i ./key ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}@host "cat /my-api/coverage-report.txt" > local-coverage-report.txt
      # Show report in logs
      cat local-coverage-report.txt
      # Share report via step output `report`
      {
        echo report<<EOF
        cat local-coverage-report.txt
        echo EOF
      } >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT

